# How to add the two map() function(bind) and display into the page? Issue on calling two maps

Tags: reactjs

In reactjs, How to add the two map() function(bind) and display into the page? Facing Issue on calling two map in reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
export default class Sampletest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      
    
        years: {
        options: [
      { value: '2021', label: '2021' },
      { value: '2020', label: '2020' },
      { value: '2019', label: '2019' },
      { value: '2018', label: '2018' },
      { value: '2017', label: '2017' },
      { value: '2016', label: '2016' },
        ],
        value: null
      },
      categories: {
        options: [
            { value: '0', label: 'Incomplete' },
            { value: '1', label: '80G' },
            { value: '2', label: '80G' },
            { value: '3', label: 'Sports' },
            { value: '4', label: 'Social welfare' },
            { value: '5', label: 'Professional' },
            { value: '6', label: 'Health' },
            { value: '7', label: 'Food and Nutrition' },
            { value: '8', label: 'Education' }
        ],
        value: null
      },
      
       Activity: {
         options: [
          { value: '0', label :'My Causes'},
          { value: '1', label :'Liked Causes'},
          { value: '2', label :'Commented Causes'},
          { value: '3', label :'Pledged Causes'}
         ],
       value: null
      }  ,
     // Details:[]
    };
  }
  onSelectChange(name, value) {
    this.setState(
      (prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          [name]: {
            ...prev[name],
            value: value.value
          }
        };
      },
      () => {
        
 let url =
 "http://localhost:88888/api/GetProfile/Get_MyPostDetails?id=" +
 this.state.Activity.value + "&Year=" +
 this.state.years.value +
 "&CategoryID=" +
 this.state.categories.value
 
 ;
 let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
 const accessToken = user;
 console.log(accessToken);
 //console.log("hi");
 fetch(url, {
   method: "GET",
   headers: {
     "Content-type": "application/json",
     Accept: "application/json",
     Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
     "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Request-Headers "
   }
   //body:JSON.stringify(data)
 })
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
        Details: data
    });
   console.log("Filter", data);
   // console.log(emps.profile_dateOfAnniversary);
 });
    }
  );
  }
  
  render() {
    const {Details} = this.state;
    return (
      
        <div>
              
        {Object.keys(this.state).map((name, i) => {
          return (
            <Select
              key={i}
              placeholder={name}
              options={this.state[name].options}
              onChange={this.onSelectChange.bind(this, name)}
            />
          );
        })}
     
          
{Details.map(emp => (
<div> 
    
<div>{emp.profile_name} </div>
</div>
))}    
 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

While Compile this code , Facing issue as--> `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`.

I have added my code , we need to add map method in the program for output and I have use this class component and calling this page into another page and display the object into array of object.

Answer (score -1):

Initialize Details as Array while declaring state.
it will be undefined on mounting face so you get the error
and check on response you are getting this response as array.

Comment: Yeah! I Declared the details as an array in state. Now My Issue was When I hide the map, I'll get the response in console. When I add the map function it shows error message "Details.map is not a function"